# dataTables not showing HTML table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an array of HTML tables that I'm building before calling dataTables but the data within my tables is not displayed once I make the call unless I place an alert in line with the code just before dataTables is called.  The code works fine unless I remove the 'alert("Stop");' line.
Below is my code excerpt:

```
    // Code above builds HTML table contents

asHTML.push("</tr>");
asHTML.push("</table>");

$("#sandBox").html(asHTML.join(''));  // Insert the lists into the DOM


$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Stop");
    for(var i=0; i<data.SANDBOX.LIST.length; i++) {

        $('#' + data.SANDBOX.LIST[i].LIST_ID).DataTable({
        autoWidth: false,
        "columnDefs": [
                {   // Hide the 'Assigned' Column
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {   // No sort on this column
                    "targets": [1],
                    "width": "1em",
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {   // No sort on this column
                    "targets": [2],
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {   // No sort on this column
                    "targets": [3],
                    "orderable": false
                }

        ],
        "paging":   false,
        "info":     false,
        "bFilter":  false,
        "scrollY": $("#parkingLot").height() - 50
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try document load instead of ready

```
$(document.body).load(function() {
//alert("Stop");
....
```

Comment: this is deprecated

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  The page is already loaded and so the load function doesn't ever execute.

Comment: @user2440948 as said, its deprecated, can you just try it as body.onload = function(){..... code here};

Comment: I did try it.  The function specified in .onload doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ready` event handler altogether, it's not needed.

```js
asHTML.push("</tr>");
asHTML.push("</table>");

$("#sandBox").html(asHTML.join(''));  // Insert the lists into the DOM

for(var i=0; i<data.SANDBOX.LIST.length; i++) { 
   // ... skipped ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but removing the "ready" has no effect.  DataTables picks up the header of the tables but no details unless I leave the alert("Stop") in place.

Comment: @user2440948, are you retrieving data via Ajax? If the data is static the code should work. If you're making Ajax request, you need initialize the table only after the request is completed. Please update your question and show how you populate your table with data.

Comment: The HTML is built from a static JSON  The code that builds the HTML iterates through the JSON manually to build the table so it is static.

Comment: @user2440948, how do you load the JSON file? Can you please demonstrate that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.  It turned out to be caused by the following line:

```
  "scrollY": $("#parkingLot").height() - 50
```

$("#parkingLot").height() was returning 0.  Evidently that element had not yet been rendered, although I thought the "ready" function would have reconciled that.

The "alert('Stop')" gave the page time to completely render the element and then it returned it's true height.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the `scrollY` in the `initComplete` event of DataTable. Your element will be rendered and available in this function.

```
$('#' + data.SANDBOX.LIST[i].LIST_ID).DataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    "columnDefs": [
            {   // Hide the 'Assigned' Column
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "orderable": false
            },
            {   // No sort on this column
                "targets": [1],
                "width": "1em",
                "orderable": false
            },
            {   // No sort on this column
                "targets": [2],
                "orderable": false
            },
            {   // No sort on this column
                "targets": [3],
                "orderable": false
            }

    ],
    "paging":   false,
    "info":     false,
    "bFilter":  false,
    initComplete: function (settings, json) {
        //do your stuff here, when everything is fully initialised and data loaded.

    }
});
```